# vkontakte api

Tags: вконтакте

Почему этот код ( виджет сообщества в контакте с моим допилом) верно работает, но отображается только на моем пк? если дать ссылку друзья, уже не отображается? Ссылка на хостинге. Я открываю, все ок, с другого пк - фэйл. http://likebox.ru/qr/cupon.html

Допил состоит в том, что определяет айди сообщества по имени и этот айди вставляется в виджет. Иначе виджет не пашет.

```
<script src="http://vkontakte.ru/js/api/openapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="vk_groups"></div>
    <script language="javascript">
        VK.init({
            apiId: 2852415 
            });
        /*function authInfo(response) {
            if (response.session) {
                alert('user: '+response.session.mid);
            } else {
                alert('not auth');
            }
        }*/
        //VK.Auth.getLoginStatus(authInfo);
        //VK.UI.button('login_button');
        VK.api('groups.getById',{gid: 'typical_proger'},function(data) {
            if (data.response) {
                // data.response is object
                // alert(data.response.gid);
                VK.Widgets.Group("vk_groups", {mode: 0, width: "380", height: "60"}, data.response[0].gid);
                }
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может потому, что для метода groups.getById нужна авторизация в вашем приложении?
А зачем вообще искать ID по имени, имя ведь измениться может. А ID сообщества можно посмотреть по ссылкам на обсуждения, стену и т.п. Например, у "Типичного программиста" ID - 30666517.